# Nice new 10.7 Lion Toolbar Items

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion

I wonder if anyone knows how to get this "Lion-style" toolbar items like we can see in Apple Mail application? Are they all custom or can be found anywhere? They are surely not present in IB.

Or are they just styled buttons and segmented controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Lion-Style" toolbar items would appear to be just Rounded Textured buttons with the image and alternate image set. You can drag these buttons directly from the IB library to your toolbar.